# Using Automapper to make full copy of an object with IList properties

Tags: c#, automapper, asp.net-4.0, castle

So I need to make copies of objects.  I have a model here "place" that has a IList HasAndBelongsToMany Property that is being a pain.  I need to take the field property and copy it too but it copies the reference only.  Here is what i have

```
public class place : ActiveRecordBase<place>
{
    public place() {  }

    private int place_id;
    [PrimaryKey("place_id")]
    virtual public int id
    {
        get { return place_id; }
        set { place_id = value; }
    }
    private IList<fields> Fields;
    [HasAndBelongsToMany(typeof(fields), Lazy = true, Table = "place_to_fields", ColumnKey = "place_id", ColumnRef = "field_id", NotFoundBehaviour = NotFoundBehaviour.Ignore, Cascade = ManyRelationCascadeEnum.AllDeleteOrphan)]
    virtual public IList<fields> field
    {
        get { return Fields; }
        set { Fields = value; }
    }
}
```

And use automapper like this

```
place org = ActiveRecordBase<place>.Find(id);

Mapper.Reset();
Mapper.CreateMap<place, place>().ForMember(dest => dest.id, o => o.Ignore())
                                .ForMember(dest => dest.field, o => o.Ignore())
                                ; 
place copy = new place();
Mapper.Map(org, copy);

copy.SaveAndFlush();
```

Which works because i'm skiping the field.  What i was hoping for was something more like:

```
Mapper.CreateMap<place, place>().ForMember(dest => dest.id, o => o.Ignore())
                                .ForMember(dest => dest.field.id, o => o.Ignore())
                                ;
```

See the first line with .ForMember(dest => dest.id, o => o.Ignore()) is so that I don't copy the reference id for the place object.  I need to do the same for the place property field.  I need to ignore the id's and make new entries with the same values on the rest of its properties

Answer (score 0):

You need to create mapping for field type and add "Ignore" option for field's id like you've alredy done for place type.

```
Mapper.CreateMap<fields, fields>().ForMember(dest => dest.id, o => o.Ignore());
Mapper.CreateMap<place, place>().ForMember(dest => dest.id, o => o.Ignore());
```

Comment: So putting the mapping for the place property as an IList<flieds> above or below does not copy the fields in the place object.  It doesn't error thou.  I would have thought that it would have to be nested to work.. ?